Gluing the outer functors between two recollements
Assume there are two recollements of triangulated categories and the functors $f_1$ and $f_3$ below.
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{rcccc}
{\mathbf{T}_1}  & \underset{\underset{i_R}\leftarrow}{\overset{\overset{i_L}\leftarrow}\to } &\mathbf{T}_2& \underset{\underset{j_R}\leftarrow}{\overset{\overset{j_L}\leftarrow}\to} &\mathbf{T}_3 \\
f_1 \downarrow  && \color{red}{\downarrow f_2}  && \downarrow f_3\\
{\mathbf{T}'_1}  & \underset{\underset{i'_R}\leftarrow}{\overset{\overset{i'_L}\leftarrow}\to } &\mathbf{T}'_2& \underset{\underset{j'_R}\leftarrow}{\overset{\overset{j'_L}\leftarrow}\to} &\mathbf{T}'_3 \\
\end{array}
\end{align*}
Is there any work which provides sufficient conditions in order to define a functor ${\color{red} f_{\color{red}2}}$ making the diagram commutative?
Commutativity means that there should be six isomorphisms of compositions of functors: $$f_1 i_L \cong i'_L f_2, \quad \ldots \quad f_2 j_R \cong j'_R f_3$$
All functors are meant to be exact functors of triangulated categories.
Thank you for reading.
